QGis plugin development: method that only runs when processing tool is opened
Is there a way to run code when a processing algorithm is clicked/opened from the QGis toolbox? I'm doing an API requests in initAlgorithm() but this also executes upon QGis startup, when QgsProcessingProvider.addAlgorithm() is called. I need the request to only run when the tool is opened from the toolbox.

Why are you doing API requests in initAlgorithm()? Is it really impossible to move it to processAlgorithm()?

The request gets dates that are used as default values for the parameters. So it would be necessary to do this in initAlgorithm()...
